Cannot use ":w !sudo tee %" with ranger + nvim
Main Problem
I'm a beginner arch user, and trying to configure my environment so that I could seamlessly edit files using ranger with nvim.
I installed ranger using the following command:
make install PREFIX=$HOME/.local
When I attempt to save a file (let's say in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf) with :x within nvim, I get an error:
E45: 'readonly' option is set (add ! to override)
This is expected, I normally proceed with executing :w !sudo tee %, and get prompted for password, type it in, and the file gets saved. However in this case I get this:
:w !sudo tee %
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required

shell returned 1

Press ENTER or type command to continue

I tried using :w !sudo -S tee % option, but when I get asked for a password, the default pass prompt gets displayed 3 times and then exits stating that the wrong password has been provided.

:w !sudo -S tee %
[sudo] password for boss: Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for boss: Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for boss: sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts

shell returned 1

Press ENTER or type command to continue


Any thoughts how this can be resolved?
Related Env Vars
EDITOR=nvim
Versions
ranger --version
ranger version: ranger 1.9.4
Python version: 3.11.8 (main, Feb 12 2024, 14:50:05) [GCC 13.2.1 20230801]

nvim --version
NVIM v0.10.1
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.1720049189
Run "nvim -V1 -v" for more info


PS in the official ranger README it's recommended using sudo make install but I'm not a fan of using sudo for userland ops.

[vi.se] would be a better place to ask this.

Maybe relevant: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/25027/saving-a-non-user-file-with-neovim-eg-root-owned-etc-pulse-default-pa

This is the approach for writing to a buffer with sudo within neovim that I came across without installing extra dependencies.
"ww" gets mapped to sudo_write:

local M = {}

function M.info(msg)
    fast_event_aware_notify(msg, vim.log.levels.INFO, {})
end

function M.warn(msg)
    fast_event_aware_notify(msg, vim.log.levels.WARN, {})
end

function M.err(msg)
    fast_event_aware_notify(msg, vim.log.levels.ERROR, {})
end

M.sudo_exec = function(cmd, print_output)
    vim.fn.inputsave()
    local password = vim.fn.inputsecret("Password: ")
    vim.fn.inputrestore()
    if not password or #password == 0 then
        M.warn("Invalid password, sudo aborted")
        return false
    end
    local out = vim.fn.system(string.format("sudo -p '' -S %s", cmd), password)
    if vim.v.shell_error ~= 0 then
        print("\r\n")
        M.err(out)
        return false
    end
    if print_output then
        print("\r\n", out)
    end
    return true
end

M.sudo_write = function(tmpfile, filepath)
    if not tmpfile then
        tmpfile = vim.fn.tempname()
    end
    if not filepath then
        filepath = vim.fn.expand("%")
    end
    if not filepath or #filepath == 0 then
        M.err("E32: No file name")
        return
    end
    -- `bs=1048576` is equivalent to `bs=1M` for GNU dd or `bs=1m` for BSD dd
    -- Both `bs=1M` and `bs=1m` are non-POSIX
    local cmd = string.format("dd if=%s of=%s bs=1048576", vim.fn.shellescape(tmpfile), vim.fn.shellescape(filepath))
    -- no need to check error as this fails the entire function
    vim.api.nvim_exec2(string.format("write! %s", tmpfile), { output = true })
    if M.sudo_exec(cmd) then
        -- refreshes the buffer and prints the "written" message
        vim.cmd.checktime()
        -- exit command mode
        vim.api.nvim_feedkeys(vim.api.nvim_replace_termcodes("<Esc>", true, false, true), "n", true)
    end
    vim.fn.delete(tmpfile)
end

vim.keymap.set("c", "ww", M.sudo_write, { silent = true })

Author: ibhagwan (https://github.com/ibhagwan). You can also find the original code here: https://github.com/ibhagwan/nvim-lua/blob/main/lua/utils.lua#L279
